# How bind vuetify skeleton-loader to v-image load event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

My target is to build a conditional rendering between `<v-skeleton-loader>`  and  `<v-card>`Skeleton binding them to a property  called `isActive`
I want that Card component only renders when the `<v-image>` has been loaded.
"Officially" based on Vuetify's guideline, the `<v-image>`  component has its own "load" event based on this sample [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1010), this could be easilly handled by calling the `loadCard(item)` and setting `isActive=true` after image has been loaded `<v-img :src="item.img" @load="loadCard(item)" >`   but it doesn't trigger on `@load`  event.

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" >  
     <v-card v-if="item.isActive">        
                        <v-img :src="item.img" @load="loadCard(item)" > 

 ......                         
</v-card> 
    <v-skeleton-loader  v-else
                    :loading="item.isActive"  
                    style="width:13.020vw; margin-bottom:2.395833vw;"
                    transition="scale-transition" 
                    type="card">
     </v-skeleton-loader>
```

I've tried to put call the function into the skeleton loaded by  `@click="loadCard(item)"`  and it works perfectly. After the click the Card renders.

```
<v-skeleton-loader  v-else 
                         @click="loadCard(item)"
                        :loading="item.isActive"  
                        style="width:13.020vw; margin-bottom:2.395833vw;"
                        transition="scale-transition" 
                        type="card">
         </v-skeleton-loader>
```

Comment: Did you end up solving this? I'm also looking for a clean way to use skeleton loaders for cards with images (since images are the obvious delay).. Would love to see that solution, in that case!

Comment: Try with v-lazy-image

Plugin

Comment: Seeing as I already use vuetify which includes skeleton loaders it would feel a shame to turn to something else..

Comment: You can integrate the Vuetify Cards  with this  plugin.